# Simple Regex slipped up by Pile Delimeter?

Tags: regex

I've a simple regex to create and for the life of me cant get it to work due to the Pipe Delimiter causing headaches.

I'm just trying to add a file extension, by looking at a previous extension, and adding that to the end of the current name.

**(Find)**

```
old.jpg|new
```

**(Replace)**

```
old.jpg|new.jpg
```

I've used a good combination but having the Pipe seems to trip me up.
Are there any suggestions or tips?

Comment: Show us what you've got so far.

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape the pipe, either with `\|` or `[|]`.

Answer (score 1):

The `|` character has special meaning. You need to escape it, for example by using a character class: `[|]`.